# Experiencing slower run times with Robolectric compared with equivalent instrumentation tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, android-instrumentation

In the past I've been writing all of my android test cases as instrumentation tests to get around the problem of mocking android specific libraries, however I know that this is not best practice. In order to conform to best practice I've attempted to convert one of my email validator test cases from an instrumentation test to a unit test.

I've successfully made the conversion, however when I compare the run time the unit test is significantly slower (6.62s as a unit test compared to 0.52s as an instrumentation test). It's worth noting that the APK does take 5s to install on the emulator which isn't accounted for in the test run report. That still means however that the unit test takes an extra second to run.

It's my understanding that unit tests should always be faster than instrumentation tests and I'd like to understand why I'm not seeing that here.

The test cases are identical for both the instrumentation and unit tests. The only difference is the package structure and at the top of the  unit test class I have `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(sdk = 28)`

For this test case I'm not using any shadows

Comment: Why do you need roboelectric for unit tests?

Comment: In this case I need robolectric for the `android.text.TextUtils` mocking

Comment: Don't mix Android classes with business logic and then you won't have this problem. Make your wrapper around `TextUtils` and mock it in unit tests.

Comment: You can not name it as a unit test since it is still emulating the whole android under the hood.

Comment: I'm not sure but if you try in config say `manifest=NONE` I might expect it will be faster

Comment: @EugenMartynov Adding `mannifest=NONE` Improved the run time marginally but it still took longer than the instrumentation test

Comment: Oke, you have to trade-off now - have it slower but without the time needed to start and setup emulator, or have it faster but with this time